# How to change popup dialog position in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, popup, vuetify.js

```
  <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog" 
      max-width="250" class="pa-6"
    >
    <v-card class="scroll"  min-height="300" max-height="700"  color="rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7)">
      
     <v-form>
         
               <v-row>
                <v-col></v-col>
                <v-col>
         
        <v-btn  class="mr-4" color="primary" style="color:white; font-weight:bold"  @click.prevent="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
                </v-col>
                <v-col></v-col>
        </v-row>
        </v-form>
      
    </v-card>
     
    
     </v-dialog>
```

This is my code of dialog component in vuetify. It's generating on the center of the screen. But I want to move it to left side corner. How i change position of this popup dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify doesn´t specify how we can change the position of the popup.

The only option here, is if you create your own style for make it.

For example, create the class .change-position

Where .change-position class has:

```
.change-position {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Good luck!